# 3D Application is not rendering the scene

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, 3d

I looked through the Microsoft page on 3D graphics and even tried to draw their example cone, but nothing's showing up on the screen. I've looked over the code several times but can't seem to find what's wrong...

**XAML code:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <MeshGeometry3D x:Key="meshPyramid" Positions="0 75 0  -50 0 50  50 0 50  50 0 -50" TriangleIndices="0 1 2  0 2 3"></MeshGeometry3D>
            <MeshGeometry3D x:Key="desertFloor" Positions="-9999,0,-9999  9999,0,-9999  9999,0,9999  -9999,0,9999" TextureCoordinates="0,0  1,0  1,1  0,1" TriangleIndices="0 1 3  1 2 3"></MeshGeometry3D>
            <DiffuseMaterial x:Key="matFont" Brush="Black">
            </DiffuseMaterial>
            <DiffuseMaterial x:Key="backFont" Brush="Firebrick"></DiffuseMaterial>
            <DiffuseMaterial x:Key="texSand">
                <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\Julko\Documents\csharpprojects\wpf\3dProj\WpfApp2\WpfApp2\sand.jpg"></ImageBrush>
                </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
            </DiffuseMaterial>
        </Grid.Resources>
        
        <Viewport3D Name ="viewPort" Width="640" Height="480">
            <Viewport3D.Camera>
                <PerspectiveCamera Position="57, 240, 41" LookDirection="-0.2, 0, -0.9" UpDirection="0, 1, 0" NearPlaneDistance="0.02" FarPlaneDistance="1000" FieldOfView="45">
                </PerspectiveCamera>
            </Viewport3D.Camera>
       
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <Model3DGroup>
                        <DirectionalLight Color="GreenYellow" Direction="1, -1, -1"/>
                        <GeometryModel3D>
                            <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                <MeshGeometry3D Positions="0.293893 -0.5 0.404509  0.475528 -0.5 0.154509  0 0.5 0  0.475528 -0.5 0.154509  0 0.5 0  0 0.5 0  0.475528 -0.5 0.154509  0.475528 -0.5 -0.154509  0 0.5 0  0.475528 -0.5 -0.154509  0 0.5 0  0 0.5 0  0.475528 -0.5 -0.154509  0.293893 -0.5 -0.404509  0 0.5 0  0.293893 -0.5 -0.404509  0 0.5 0  0 0.5 0  0.293893 -0.5 -0.404509  0 -0.5 -0.5  0 0.5 0  0 -0.5 -0.5  0 0.5 0  0 0.5 0  0 -0.5 -0.5  -0.293893 -0.5 -0.404509  0 0.5 0  -0.293893 -0.5 -0.404509  0 0.5 0  0 0.5 0  -0.293893 -0.5 -0.404509  -0.475528 -0.5 -0.154509  0 0.5 0  -0.475528 -0.5 -0.154509  0 0.5 0  0 0.5 0  -0.475528 -0.5 -0.154509  -0.475528 -0.5 0.154509  0 0.5 0  -0.475528 -0.5 0.154509  0 0.5 0  0 0.5 0  -0.475528 -0.5 0.154509  -0.293892 -0.5 0.404509  0 0.5 0  -0.293892 -0.5 0.404509  0 0.5 0  0 0.5 0  -0.293892 -0.5 0.404509  0 -0.5 0.5  0 0.5 0  0 -0.5 0.5  0 0.5 0  0 0.5 0  0 -0.5 0.5  0.293893 -0.5 0.404509  0 0.5 0  0.293893 -0.5 0.404509  0 0.5 0  0 0.5 0  " 
    Normals="0.7236065,0.4472139,0.5257313  0.2763934,0.4472138,0.8506507  0.5308242,0.4294462,0.7306172  0.2763934,0.4472138,0.8506507  0,0.4294458,0.9030925  0.5308242,0.4294462,0.7306172  0.2763934,0.4472138,0.8506507  -0.2763934,0.4472138,0.8506507  0,0.4294458,0.9030925  -0.2763934,0.4472138,0.8506507  -0.5308242,0.4294462,0.7306172  0,0.4294458,0.9030925  -0.2763934,0.4472138,0.8506507  -0.7236065,0.4472139,0.5257313  -0.5308242,0.4294462,0.7306172  -0.7236065,0.4472139,0.5257313  -0.858892,0.429446,0.279071  -0.5308242,0.4294462,0.7306172  -0.7236065,0.4472139,0.5257313  -0.8944269,0.4472139,0  -0.858892,0.429446,0.279071  -0.8944269,0.4472139,0  -0.858892,0.429446,-0.279071  -0.858892,0.429446,0.279071  -0.8944269,0.4472139,0  -0.7236065,0.4472139,-0.5257313  -0.858892,0.429446,-0.279071  -0.7236065,0.4472139,-0.5257313  -0.5308242,0.4294462,-0.7306172  -0.858892,0.429446,-0.279071  -0.7236065,0.4472139,-0.5257313  -0.2763934,0.4472138,-0.8506507  -0.5308242,0.4294462,-0.7306172  -0.2763934,0.4472138,-0.8506507  0,0.4294458,-0.9030925  -0.5308242,0.4294462,-0.7306172  -0.2763934,0.4472138,-0.8506507  0.2763934,0.4472138,-0.8506507  0,0.4294458,-0.9030925  0.2763934,0.4472138,-0.8506507  0.5308249,0.4294459,-0.7306169  0,0.4294458,-0.9030925  0.2763934,0.4472138,-0.8506507  0.7236068,0.4472141,-0.5257306  0.5308249,0.4294459,-0.7306169  0.7236068,0.4472141,-0.5257306  0.8588922,0.4294461,-0.27907  0.5308249,0.4294459,-0.7306169  0.7236068,0.4472141,-0.5257306  0.8944269,0.4472139,0  0.8588922,0.4294461,-0.27907  0.8944269,0.4472139,0  0.858892,0.429446,0.279071  0.8588922,0.4294461,-0.27907  0.8944269,0.4472139,0  0.7236065,0.4472139,0.5257313  0.858892,0.429446,0.279071  0.7236065,0.4472139,0.5257313  0.5308242,0.4294462,0.7306172  0.858892,0.429446,0.279071  "                   TriangleIndices="0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 " />
                            </GeometryModel3D.Geometry></GeometryModel3D>
                        <GeometryModel3D Geometry='{StaticResource meshPyramid}' Material='{StaticResource matFont}' BackMaterial='{StaticResource backFont}'/>
                        <GeometryModel3D Geometry='{StaticResource desertFloor}' Material='{StaticResource texSand}'/>
                    </Model3DGroup>
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
            
        </Viewport3D>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position of camera is wrong. Change it e.g. to the

`PerspectiveCamera Position="57, 41, 240"`

and you will see pyramid. Just do play with `Position`, `UpDirection`, `LookDirection`.
Also do swap `Material` and `BackMaterial` by `meshPyramid`:

```
<GeometryModel3D Geometry='{StaticResource meshPyramid}' Material='{StaticResource backFont}' BackMaterial='{StaticResource matFont}'/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried to visualize the camera again from your position and it now makes sense. I gotta get better at thinking in 3D. What did you mean by swapping Material and BackMaterial by meshPyramid? meshPyramid is the meshGeometry3D object so it cannot be used as a material.